# Inheritance with maven plugins

Tags: java, maven, plugins

I want to use maven to insert the plugin configuration from a separate repo into my project.

The separate repo has the following structure:
"my-check"

- pom.xml
- module "my-archunit-plugin-config"
  -pom.xml

My other java project is a simple spring boot project. it is named "my-bookshop".
I want to include the parent pom of "my-check" , so that all modules especially the plugin configuration will be inheritated to "my-bookshop".

The content of the pom of "my-archunit-plugin-config" is:

```
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.plugin</groupId>
        <artifactId>my-check</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1</version>
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.plugin</groupId>
    <artifactId>my-archunit-plugin-config</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>


 <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.societegenerale.commons</groupId>
                <artifactId>arch-unit-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
                <configuration>                
                    <excludedPaths>
                        <!-- exclude cds gen path -->
                        <excludedPath>${basedir}/src/gen/java/cds/gen</excludedPath>
                        <excludedPath>${basedir}/src/test</excludedPath>
                    </excludedPaths>

                    <rules>
                        <!-- using a rule available out of the box... -->
                        <preConfiguredRules>                            <rule>com.societegenerale.commons.plugin.rules.NoStandardStreamRuleTest</rule>
                            <configurableRule>
                                <rule>com.rules.RuleTest1</rule>
                                <applyOn>
                                    <packageName>com.factory</packageName>
                                    <!-- scope can be "main" or "test" -->
                                    <scope>test</scope>
                                </applyOn>
                            </configurableRule>
                        </configurableRules>
                    </rules>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>arch-test</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>com.plugins.commons</groupId>
                        <artifactId>commons-archunit</artifactId>
                        <version>2.0.1</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>
```

How can i do this?
I tried it by using the as dependency or in dependency management or as plugin management. But nothing works. If look with in intellij in the "my-check" project i see the plugin. But if i look into "my-bookshop" where i tried to resolve also the plugin then it is not where. How can i achieve it?

Im using Maven 3.8.1

Comment: I do not quite understand. You can configure a plugin in a parent POM and then use it (with the configuration)  in a child POM.